# icCube : how to enable Gzip Compression for Excel xmla requests?

Tags: excel, gzip, connection-string, oledbconnection, iccube

When I run http://192.168.1.207:8282/icCube/xmla  request in navigator, Gzip compression is used.

[image]

When using excel to query on the same (local) server thru MSOLAP.6, everything works correctly, but there is no GZIP compression. (no compression at all)

I tried to add

```
Transport Compression=gzip
```

to my connection string as mentionned here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/instances/connection-string-properties-analysis-services?view=sql-server-2017

```
   <odc:ConnectionString>Provider=MSOLAP.6;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=admin;Data Source=http://192.168.1.207:8282/icCube/xmla;Initial Catalog=Sales;MDX Missing Member Mode=Ignore;Protocol Format=XML;Transport Compression=gzip</odc:ConnectionString>
```

but, doing this, I get the following error while tring to connect
[image]
(Failed to initialize data source)

I also tried with

```
Transport Compression=Compressed
```

This allows to connect and query the cube using excel, but witout any compression.

This is very annoying regarding to the gain that compression would give.
Please Help!

Answer (score 1):

This is more a question for Excel configuration: I believe Excel does not allow for standard HTTP compression on the wire. I believe MS is using a proprietary protocol  for that purpose.

Perhaps as a workaround would be to configure somehow a proxy in the machine hosting Excel: that proxy could be configured to use standard HTTP compression when talking to icCube.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, it's certainly more excel related, that's why I tagged "excel" as well. Proxy solution is difficult to set up on each client station. Excel pros ? any comment ?  would it be possible to "catch" and unzip responses via VBA ?

Comment: there are not a lot of MS guys here, maybe MS forum